# Do dirty air filters trap more or less dust and dirt?

Tags: air-quality, air-filter

I read the following on the internet:

> Letting air flow past a dirty filter introduces a lot of dust and airborne particulates into your ductwork and your home’s air.

I found the following comment from [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/206583/131044):

> ...I read a scientific article on air particle filters that said that filters generally increase in filtration performance as they get more clogged. If this is true, the time to change a filter is just when it doesn't pass enough air (has too much back pressure) for the system it's in to operate correctly.

Which view is correct in regards to particles passing through a dirty air filter? In my opinion the later seems correct, but that's just intuition, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Filtration performance should not increase.  The air flow should decrease.  Depending on the sealing, more dirty air might flow around the filter instead of going though it when it becomes dirty.

Comment: Both are correct. The 1st quote is referring to a situation where the dirty filter is being bypassed - the air is flowing *around* it (for unspecified reasons) not *through* it.

Comment: Reduced porosity improves catching smaller and smaller particles trading off with the amount of airflow which requires more power to pull through the air whose flow is restricted.

Comment: This is true of HEPA filters at least. I do not know about all mechanical filters and would not generalize.

Comment: The performance of an air filter **is** how well it passes air! The fact that it traps particles over a certain size is taken for granted. An ideal filter would pose zero resistance to the flow of air, while retaining the unwanted particles.

Answer (score 8):

A new clean filter has pores or mesh of a certain size. As material accumulates on the face of the filter, pore size within the accumulated material tends to get smaller. In that sense, the size of things it traps will be reduced.

This effect is commonly used in things like a diatomaceous earth filter, where a relatively porous filter base gets a "filter cake" built up on it by mixing D.E. into the liquid to be filtered and recirculating it until the filter bed is established and the discharge runs clear (which happens to be commonly in filtering maple syrup.) The base filter medium only needs to stop the DE particles, and then the main filtering is done by the smaller spaces in the layer of DE particles.

Airflow through the filter will decrease, and pressure across the filter will increase as dirt accumulates on the intake face. If pressure increases enough, it may rupture the base filter material, though that's unlikely in most air-handling filter setups. When I change my car's air filter, the backside looks perfectly clean, but the front side is filthy. If dirt were being "pulled through" that would not be the case.

However, some HVAC filters may be so coarse that vibrations may shake accumulated dirt loose and allow the finer particles temporarily trapped to be pulled through. And in any case overall system performance will drop due to reduced airflow.

Comment: Decades ago many computers included fan filters that could be removed/cleaned. But as computers became smaller/cheaper (no longer limited to big companies with people who knew how/when to do maintenance) this became a problem because people might *never* bother to clean the filter until it became so caked with dirt that the computer overheated due to limited airflow. Solution: No filters at all. But with the side effect that many times when I open a computer that has been running for a few years it is loaded with dirt inside.

Answer (score 3):

Ecnerwal wrote:

> A new clean filter has pores or mesh of a certain size. As material accumulates on the face of the filter, pore size within the accumulated material tends to get smaller. In that sense, the size of things it traps will be reduced.

I agree.  There are (at least) three factors to consider in addition to the above:

1. As the material accumulates on the filter, less air will likely pass through the filter in a given period of time.  Thus, the overall volume of air being cleaned per hour is diminished.
2. As the material accumulates on the filter, unfiltered airflow will increase in any areas surrounding the filter.  For example, many large HVAC filters are located in a dedicated filter box.  Such filter boxes rarely *perfectly* fit the filters that go within.  Thus, as material accumulates on the filter, more unfiltered air will pass *around* the filter.
3. Motors can be strained when they have to pump air through clogged filters, possibly shortening the life of the motors.

In my view, it's all a balancing act to produce the air quality you are trying to achieve.  The factors being balanced are convenience, cost, air quality, risk, and health.  In commercial installations, there could also be legal and/or regulatory factors, but those are outside the scope of this Stack Exchange site.

Comment: thanks for the reply. how can a motor be strained from having a clogged filter?  the temp sensor is only a gauge not a requirement

Comment: You're welcome.  Your question in your comment is a very good one (and may warrant it's own full-fledged question).  If you will, read the answers to the following question, and see if they help: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/257539/why-is-a-merv-16-filter-not-recommended-for-residential-furnace-use-urban-myth